# How do I visualise this diagram and answer the integration (volume) question

Tags: integration

> Two half cylinders of diameter 8 meet at a right angle in the figure shown below. Find the volume of the solid region common to both half cylinders.

[image]

To find volume, I understand that we have to do integration: $V = \int_a^b A(x) dx$

I do not know how to visualise the cross-sectional area in this problem.

I been told to let $x$ represent the perpendicular distance up from the base of the solid. The cross sectional area from the diagram looks like a square with sides 8 units. But that is wrong. How do I find and visualise the side of a square to find $A(x)$?

Comment: See [Steinmetz solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid)

Answer (score 1):

If you look from above, both cylinders would look like long rectangles, so when you intersect two similar ones, the cross-section must be a square.

[image: cross-section]

Let us write the equations of both half-cylinders as
$$x^2 + z^2 = 16, \quad y^2 + z^2 = 16\quad \forall z > 0$$
The equation of the square would be $A = xy$, and since $x = y$ in a square, the area $a(z)$ as a function of $z$ would be:
$$a(z) = xy = x^2 = 16 - z^2.$$
But **remember** that the total square would be of length $2x$ and $2y$ since there is a $+x$ side and a $-x$ side. Therefore, we have to multiply the total area by $2^2 = 4$, giving
$$A(z) = 4(16 - z^2).$$
Now we can integrate by finding an infinitesimal volume piece $\text{d}V = A(z) \text{d}z$ or
$$V = \int_{0}^4 4(16 - z^2) \text{d}z = \left.4\left(16x - \frac{x^3}{3}\right)\right|_{0}^{4} = \frac{512}{3}.$$

Comment: See [Steinmetz solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid)

Comment: Ah this is quite cool, nice link!